# Почему блок не выравнивается по центру другого блока?

Tags: html, css

Почему блок с классом `c2` не выравнивается по центру блока с классом `c1`?

```css
.c1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}
.c2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="c1">
<div class="c2">

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так (сделать с2 строчным элементом):

```
.c1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
}
.c2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Больше способов [здесь](http://frontender.info/centering-css-complete-guide/)

Answer (score 2):

Прежде всего, `vertical-align` применяется только к строчным элементам или ячейкам таблицы: [описание vertical-align](https://webref.ru/css/vertical-align)

> **Применяется**:  *К строчным элементам или ячейкам таблицы*

Однако, если вы зададите строчный вариант отображения внутреннему блоку, применение `vertical-align` к нему ничего не даст, поскольку  строчные блоки выравниваются по вертикали относительно соседних блоков, а в вашем случае блок всего один.

Делать внешний блок таблицей только для выравнивания тоже не очень разумно, ибо семантически это будет неверно.

Можете использовать свойство `line-height`, значение которого будет равно высоте внешнего блока. Но если высота будет неизвестна, то такой способ тоже не универсальный.

Можете выбрать себе наиболее подходящий способ выравнивания по вертикали по ссылке: [Все способы вертикального выравнивания в CSS](https://habrahabr.ru/company/netcracker/blog/277433/)

Answer (score 1):

vertical-align: middle; оно работает только для строчных элементов и ячеек таблиц. Если хотите сделать для блоков то можно так:

```css
.c1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle; /* выравнивание по высоте */
  text-align: center; /* выравнивание по ширине */
}
.c2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="c1">
<div class="c2">

</div>
</div>
```