# Почему не работает vertical-align у table-cell, если элемент absolute?

Tags: html, css, position, display

```
.callUs {
  position: absolute;
  display: table-cell; 
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle; /* Не работает! */
  width: 50px; height: 50px;
  bottom: 50px; right: 50px; 
  border: 1px solid black; 
  background: lime;
}

*{box-sizing: border-box;}
```

Почему-то не работает вертикальное выравнивание содержимого, если задать абсолютное позиционирование. Казалось бы, никакой связи, все установлено корректно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Применение свойства `position: absolute;` автоматически присваивает блоку свойство `display: block;`. Если превращение блока в ячейку таблицы использовано только для вертикального центрирования, то стоит попробовать [другие техники](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/524061/196573)

Comment: Благодарю за ответ.

Comment: мне кажется, inline-block....